# DataGridView AutoComplete TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted autocomplete textbox in datagridview column no 0 and 1 but it is showing in autocomplete result 2 and 3 and 4 columns also even after I specify index as

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
   { // code }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: any body please suggest

Comment: According to the rules you need to provide a code to reproduce the problem. This code line works so I'm voting to close.